# Translating and localizing technical words into other languages

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation, google-translate

I'm currently translating a website from english into other languages but have a problem when it comes to technical terms (non words) like "crontab".

Should I keep the english translation or is there another way to find the equivalent?

These aren't actually english words and when it comes to languages like Japanese, I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Here's an example sentence as an example:

**"Use crontab to schedule scripts."**

which translated into Japanese via Google Translate becomes:

**"スクリプトをスケジュールするcrontabを使用してください。"**

You can see how bizarre this looks, and I'm wondering if the sentence could even be understood by a Japanese speaker.

What do I do in these situations?

Answer (score 1):

**Using English words in Japanese**

Talking about the word `crontab`, I think it's not bizarre to write it in English in a Japanese sentence like this:

```
crotabを使用してください
(please use crontab)
```

On Japanese wikipedia, you can see how `crontab` is used without translating into Japanese.
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

In Japanese technical writing, especially when you mention name of tools, it is common to use English as it is without translating into Japanese.

---

**Using Katakana**

You could also write the sentence like below using Katakana.

```
クーロンタブを使用してください
(please use crontab).
```

Japanese usually writes words from English in Katakana. Japanese Katakana is phonetic, in other words each character represents a sound (not meaning). But In this case, it doesn't look natural.

---

**Mistranslation**

There is a mistranslation in your Japanese sentence.

```
 スクリプトをスケジュールするcrontabを使用してください。
 (Please use crontab which scedule a script.)
```

To correct this, you could go like this:

```
 スクリプトをスケジュールするには、crontabを使用してください。
 (In order to schedule a script, please use crontab.)
```

Hope this helps.